# Globalisation and Date Conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, language-translation

I consume a web service that gives me dates in English short format i.e. 21 Mar 2015. The site then displays the date in the correct language. This works fine for all languages (en, de, es, it, hu) EXCEPT for when the month is March  (Mar). Then it fails in es and it only.

I've tried implicit date conversion as well as Date.Parse(somedatestring). Both give the same results.

The site is WebForms .NET 4.5 VB on a Win 2012 server IIS8.  I'm completely stumped.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some code or a example to reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

This code works with your string and `es-ES` culture(spanish):

```
var esCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
var format = "dd MMM yyyy";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("21 Mar 2015", format, esCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed successfully: " + dt.ToString());
}
```

But since `Mar` is the english(and apparently spanish as well) abbreviation for the month march, you can enforce it work for every language by using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("21 Mar 2015", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt));
```

If you want to convert the `DateTime` to the correct language you can use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
var cultures = new[] { 
    CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"),
    CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES"), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT"), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hu-HU")
};
foreach(var culture in cultures)
     Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", culture));
```

**Edit**: Sorry for C#, i hope you get the idea anyway.

Comment: The weird thing is that the site is already in the correct culture and works for all other languages except es and it and only for Mar. For dates other than Mar, the pages is in the right languages and shows the appropriate date formats etc.  It's as if there's an issue with .NET 4.5 which the site has just been recompiled to.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent by using culture-specific format information.

```
Dim d As Date = Date.Parse("21 Mar 2015", New CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim. Sorted it with:-

```
Public Shared Function translateDate(ByVal passedDate As String)
    Dim outputDate As Date
    Dim isDate As Boolean = DateTime.TryParseExact(passedDate, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture(), DateTimeStyles.None, outputDate)
    outputDate = If(isDate, outputDate, "No Date")
    Return outputDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work after all. There is nothing wrong anywhere unless the month in March, then it doesn't work for ES and IT. It's the same even if I force conversion from 21 Mar 2014 to 21/03/2014 with invariant culture then force the output date object to output as a string with outputDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)